# Give Input from Text file to Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

In my ansible playbook I want to get the input from text file and perform some set of operations.
I have 10 user names in the text file, then the play has to pick first name from the text file and do few tasks. Once done for the first user and the play has to pick it for second user and so on.

I wrote play for a single user. Kindly help me or give some sample play for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Hi. Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Its important that you show your attempted code in question.

Comment: @Srikanth Venugopalan did my answer help ?

Comment: @AbraamMagued I yet to check. I'll check it today and update you.

Answer (score 2):

*You should be using roles and manage everything from inventory.*

But however, simplest way; Create a file, and store your user names in a variable that way

```
users:
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3
    - user4
    - user5
```

At the beginning of your playbook, include that file

```
- hosts: whatever
  become: yes
  vars_file: 
     - <<path_to_your_var_file>>
```

Then in the task you can use that **users** variable you included from the variable file

```
  tasks:
    - name: create 10 users
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - "{{ users }}"
```

Ansible will import the **users** variable from your var file, and loop n times with number of users you have.

Comment: https://www.toptechskills.com/ansible-tutorials-courses/ansible-include-import-variables-tutorial-examples/ This gives an example that's good in addition to your good answer.  One note.  The file you're creating is a **vars** file.  These can be INI or YAML, but YAML is clean and easy and familiar for Ansible.  `uservars.yml` would be better than `users`.  Also it's good practice to start a YAML file with `---` on the first line.

Answer (score -1):

`vars_file` module seems to not be currently available so I used this instead:

```
name: load names 

include_vars:

    file: /etc/ansible/users
```